# Drag Drop on IE9 like skydrive

Tags: drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-9, onedrive

Hi i've been looking for away to drag drop file upload. I know it possible to use html 5 file API to do this on other browser like chrome but not on IE 9.  However i noticed that you can drag drop upload on the Sky-drive site using IE 9.

I was just wondering what they used to do this? I've got a feeling it might be silver-light but could be totally wrong.

If anyone could give me an insight that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SkyDrive works with Silverlight, or uses HTML5 when available (Internet Explorer 10, Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari).

Since IE9 does not support HTML5, SkyDrive uses Silverlight on that browser.